# Cron in postgresql:alpine docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, cron, docker-container

I am using the "plain" postgresql:alpine docker image, but have to schedule a database backup daily. I think this is a pretty common task.

I created a script `backup`and stored in the container in `/etc/periodic/15min`, and made it executable:

```
bash-4.4# ls -l /etc/periodic/15min/
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            95 Mar  2 15:44 backup
```

I tried executing it manually, that works fine.

**My problem is getting `crond` to run  automatically.**

If I exec `docker exec my-postgresql-container crond`, the deamon is started and cron works, but **I would like to embed this into my Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:alpine

# my backup script, MUST NOT have .sh extension
COPY backup.sh /etc/periodic/15min/backup 
RUN chmod a+x /etc/periodic/15min/backup

RUN crond # <- doesn't work
```

I have no idea how to rewrite or overwrite the commands in the official image. For update reasons I also would like to stay on these images, if possible.

Comment: I was facing the same problem but did not want to go down the road of multiple services. In my case i built a separate container: https://github.com/piccaso/docker-postgres-backup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Note: This option if you would like to use the same container with [multiple service](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

Install [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which will makes you able to run `crond` and `postgresql`. The `Dockerfile` will be as the following:

```
FROM postgres:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor
RUN mkdir /etc/supervisor.d
COPY postgres_cron.ini /etc/supervisor.d/postgres_cron.ini
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

And `postgres_cron.ini` will be as the following:

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
nodaemon=true              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)

[program:postgres]
command=/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:cron]
command =/usr/sbin/crond -f
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Then you can start the docker build process and run a container from your new image. Feel free to modify the `Dockerfile` or `postgres_cron.ini` as needed

Comment: Dear Mostafa, thank you very much for this complete answer. You have given me the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem a few month ago. The key aspect is that a container can have only one main process defined by the `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`.

You cannot just swap out `postgres` with `crond` otherwise your database isn't running. It is generally recommended to separate areas of concern by using one service per container.

---

With that in mind either use a separate container which runs nothing but `crond` and thus `Docker` can both track its lifecycle, and restart it when/if it fails, the machine restarts, etc.

Or run the jobs via `cron` on your host using `docker exec`.

The third and in my opinion best (but also advanced) solution is [`pg_cron`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron). It is an `postgres` extension and therefore runs the jobs in the same database container. Your challenge would be to adapt the configuration and installation of it.

The easy part should be the 
[`postgresql.conf`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron#setting-up-pg_cron):

```
# add to postgresql.conf:
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
cron.database_name = 'postgres'
```

Next, you need to add the `pg_cron` extension to your image by adjusting the `Dockerfile`, which you can derive from the official `alpine postgres` image. The installation of it is described [here](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron#installing-pg_cron).

Comment: Thanks Yannic! But why is it not possible to "swap out postgres with crond"? If I exec a bash and run crond in background, it works... It seem I have not understood the docker concept in this aspect...

Comment: @OlliD-Metz the general goal of docker is to deploy a single piece of functionality. In your case it's PG. While you can use bash against it, that's a secondary effect of the VM containing an OS at its base. Wha Yannic is that you should have 2 containers: PG and a cron job container that does what ever you need to do. So the 2nd container would get run every 15 minutes to pack up the DB.