# docker supervisor symfony command

Tags: symfony, docker, supervisord

I want to control php processes (symfony commands) by supervisor.
Symfony commands run in php-fpm docker container.
Is possible to run separated docker container with supervisor to controll processes running in the container. With php?

Comment: Please reformulate your question. I am not sure what you mean at all. Do you want to separate the html stack from console commands (`bin/console`)?

Comment: Simply I want to have two containers, one with supervisor and second with php. Supervisor will be controll php process in php container. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you searching for a way to run cron-jobs? I solved this like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074458/cron-in-postgresqlalpine-docker-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I was researching various approaches to this just yesterday, in need to `RabbitMQ` consumer command to run side by side to my Symfony-based app.

My first thought was to separate containers as they really seem independent, after all, they would target the same DBMS server. But I had a problem in my head of needing a complete copy of my app in some container whilst using only small portion of it, so I turned my head to having only one container.

General idea is to change docker startup `CMD`, so it does not run the `php-fpm`, but `supervisor` instead. Then, one of `supervisor`'s programs should be original docker startup script, and another one could be your command. I am not sure if there are some blow backs from this, but one that comes to my mind is that if `php` crashes, you would rely on `supervisor` to bring it back. If this fails, your are stuck in believing that everything is in order, but in fact it is not.

The idea from above is very well described here: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6tik/using-supervisor-withing-docker-containers

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -2):

we are using

```
container_id=`docker ps -q --no-trunc --filter label="com.amazonaws.ecs.container-name=php" | head -n 1`; docker exec $container_id php /var/www/application/bin/console app:cronjob
```

to access the PHP container.

If you are not using EC2 you might have to change the filter value.