# How can I create a docker image that is schedules to run a cron task and also running mysqldump

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, cron

I have a scenario where I have to deploy a docker container that is running a `cron` task.
It would be running a shell script scheduled to generate dumps for a mysql database in a configured time. Where the mysql container is completely separate.

such as `myscript.sh`

`nice -n 10 ionice -c2 -n 7 mysqldump --quick --quote-names --max_allowed_packet=1024M --routines --skip-tz-utc --default_character_set utf8 -P xxxx -hmysql -uroot -pMyPassword MyDatabase > /db_backups/NewSQL_dump.sql`

-- Consider above is the script I have to run.

Which is scheduled as:

`00 05 * * * /etc/cron.d/myscript.sh >> /var/log/dump.log`

For the `myscript.sh` and `crontabs` files I can probably be able to bind them like below:

`docker run -d -v /myscript.sh:/etc/cron.d/ -v /crontabs:var/spool/cron/crontabs ...`

But I also have to have `mysql` and `mysqldump` in the container.

What is the way to do these all.

Comment: Also `db_backups` will be bind to a location in the host.

Comment: If you install the MySQL client tools on the host, you can set up an ordinary cron job to do this; you don't need Docker at all (even if the database happens to be running in a container).

Comment: first: be careful with your script name, cron dislikes `.sh`. Second, maybe you have to look into supervisor in order to get two concurrent daemons running in one container,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49074458

Comment: If you're putting this into its own container and there's no other crons, you may as well make the script the entrypoint and make your script do end endless loop with `sleep 3600` between dumps.

Comment: @DavidMaze Its a ec2 instance. It creates a new ec2 instance every time a deployment performed.